# Show that sentence $ ∃x∀y∃z((F(y, z) → F(x, z)) → (F(x, x) → F(y, x))) $ is true in every finite model but it is not a valid formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, satisfiability

∃x∀y∃z((F(y, z) → F(x, z)) → (F(x, x) → F(y, x)))

How can I show for this formula that it is true in every finite model but it isn't a valid formula?

Can someone please help me solve this problem/send me the proof/send me links of books where I can find a proof of this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? There are two things to show here - have you made any progress in either of them? Questions that look like "do my homework for me" are typically not well-received here.

Comment: @AlexKruckman
I actually have problems with the first part-to show that the sentence is true in every finite model, if it is okay to ask how can I do it(?)The second part I think I did well...Thank you.

Comment: In that case, you should really edit your question to explain your solution to the second part. This would be really helpful context - not only does it demonstrate some effort on your part, it will also give people something to work with in answering the first part. And it could be helpful to you, since you might get some critiques or improvements on your solution.